# Why cannot access file in Google Drive folder by using Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter

Today I have problem when access Google drive folder on PC through Jupyter Notebook. The last time I still able to save the .ipynb file inside all folder that contain in google drive folder as well as open them by using Jupyter. The problem is as the picture below, while in fact, there are many folders inside.
[image]

How to fix this problem? If not how to access .ipynb file there or I need to go to file explorer then move it to Desktop to use everytime, It waste lots of time. 
Thanks!

Comment: Check the permissions of the folder. If you are using linux, and if you see a lock symbol on the folder, then you will have to change the permissions of the folder. In other os also, check the folders permissions.

Comment: I'm using window :(

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, not able to access Google Drive through Jupyter notebook. I found this great blog and solved my problem. I am sure it will helpful for you, too! Thank you @JohnWhite and @hometechtime.

Here is the link:
https://hometechtime.com/open-jupyter-notebook-files-saved-in-google-drive-file-stream/

I will explain in steps in case the blog is removed.

1. Open Command Prompt in Windows
2. Find your user directory in windows file explorer. For example "C:\Users\MehmetYildirim"
3. Find the drive letter that Google Drive uses. For example "G:"
4. Finally, you need to type the following in the command prompt:
   `mklink /J "C:\Users\Mehmet Yildirim\Google Drive" "G:\"` or try this `C:\Users\Mehmet Yildirim>mklink /J "C:\Users\Mehmet Yildirim\Google Drive" "G:\"`

You will see that you can access to Google Drive folder through Jupyter notebook.

Comment: Any hint on how to do this for mac?

Comment: Sorry, I am not using a mac. But, I found this link: https://bugs.python.org/issue33935 . It might be helpful. Would you like to give it a try?

Comment: Thank you Mehmet, but it did not work out since it does not mention issues with denied permissions on Google Drive